# Error loading 1000+ records from server with $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I am fetching records from database using json in $.ajax and asp.net.

Everything works fine but when the number of records is larger than 1000 then it crashes and shows "500 (Internal Server Error)" error message.

jQuery Code

```
    $.ajax({ type: "post",
        url: "Default.aspx/SELECT_ALL",
        data: _data,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d != null || data.d != 'null') {
                var Items = data.d;

                if (Items.length > 0) {

                    // Create Table header and prepare the body
                    $.fn.create_table();

                    for (var r = 0; r < Items.length; r++) {

                        // Add new row and columns
                        var tRow = tBody.insertRow(-1);
                        for (var x = 0; x < Cols.length; x++) {
                            var td = tRow.insertCell(-1);
                            var input = document.createElement('input');
                            input.type = 'text';
                            input.id = columns[x] + '-' + row;

                            if (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3) {
                                input.setAttribute("class", "validate text");
                            } else if (x == 4) {
                                input.setAttribute("class", "validate number number-only");
                            }

                            if (x == 0) {
                                input.type = 'checkbox';
                                input.value = row;
                            } else {
                                switch (x) {
                                    case 1:
                                        //input.value = Items[r].BMLCode;
                                        td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="' + columns[x] + '-' + row + '" value="' + Items[r].Code + '" /><input type="hidden" name="ID" id="ID" value="' + Items[r].ID + '" /><input type="hidden" name="updated" id="updated" />';
                                        break;

                                    case 2:
                                        input.value = Items[r].Description;
                                        break;

                                    case 3:
                                        input.value = Items[r].Unit;
                                        break;

                                    case 4:
                                        input.value = Items[r].Price;
                                        input.setAttribute("onblur", '$.fn.adRow(' + r + ');');
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        input.value = 'Error';
                                        break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (x == 0) {
                                td.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="' + columns[x] + '-' + row + '" value="' + row + '" /><label>' + row + '</label>';
                            } else if ($.inArray(x, [1, 3, 4, 5])) {
                                td.appendChild(input);
                            }

                            if (x >= columns.length - 1) {
                                row++;

                                $(".number-only").each(function () {
                                    $(this).numberBox();
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $.fn.create_table();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

ASP.NET Code

```
#region Items
public class clsCodes
{
    public string ID { set; get; }
    public string Code { set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }
    public string Unit { set; get; }
    public string Rate { set; get; }
}
#endregion


#region Select All
[WebMethod]
public static clsCodes[] SELECT_ALL(string Activity_ID)
{
    try
    {
        List<clsCodes> _Return = new List<clsCodes>();
        Database db = new Database();
        DataTable table = null;

        Dictionary<string, object> Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Parameters.Add("Procedure", "usp_codes");
        Parameters.Add("@Activity_ID", MajorActivity_ID);

        db.Open();
        table = db.ExecuteTable(Parameters);
        db.Close();

        if (table != null && table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int iRow = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dRow in table.Rows)
            {
                if (iRow >= 1000)
                {
                    break;
                }
                clsCodes _Code = new clsCodes();
                _Code.ID = dRow["ID"].ToString();
                _Code.Code = dRow["Code"].ToString();
                _Code.Description = dRow["Description"].ToString();
                _Code.Unit = dRow["Unit"].ToString();
                _Code.Rate = dRow["Rate"].ToString();
                _Return.Add(_Code);

                iRow++;
            }
        }
        return _Return.ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
#endregion
```

Note: I am using HTML DOM Table Object in javascript to create a table.

Comment: Note an answer - but 1000 records is a lot to be displaying all at once on a front end.  Have you considered paging?

Comment: I agree with @Paddy. 1k+ records is *far* too many to show on the UI. If you need the user to have access to that much data you need to use a combination of searching, filtering and paging.

Answer (score 1):

how much rows you got in the table?

```
if (table != null && table.Rows.Count > 0) {
    int iRow = 0;
    foreach(DataRow dRow in table.Rows) {
        if (iRow >= 1000) {
            break;
        }
        clsCodes _Code = new clsCodes();
        _Code.ID = dRow["ID"].ToString();
        _Code.Code = dRow["Code"].ToString();
        _Code.Description = dRow["Description"].ToString();
        _Code.Unit = dRow["Unit"].ToString();
        _Code.Rate = dRow["Rate"].ToString();
        _Return.Add(_Code);

        iRow++;
    }
}
return _Return.ToArray();
```

because of the "500 Server Error" the problem have to be in your ASP.net Code

maybe there is an unknown exception in

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    return null;
}
```

it works with 999 rows?!

Comment: Its not ASP.NET error, I checked I am getting 3000 records in my DataTable and ignore the line `if (iRow >= 1000) {` I was just testing.

Comment: It is an error on your server side code - not your client side.  The clues in the error name.

Comment: please substitute "return null" with "System.out.println(ex);ex.printStackTrace();" and test again.. if there is an error - paste it here..

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is very old but I just faced a similar issue on page which require large data to show and I used the server side pagination to fetch the data with user scroll action.

The request always failed when the number of records reach 1000 no matter what batch size I used.

The reason was I was creating the checkboxes on the returned data to select the individual records for further action to perform and posting the form data with ajax request

I was also using parse_str on server side which process the pagination request so the request failed basically due to "max_input_vars" which is default to 1000

The work around is change this setting in your php.ini file and it should work fine but not all hosting providers allow to change this or at least I am unaware of if they do.

I'll have another work around so that a max of 1000 records or processed per batch.

Hope it shall save some one else day